# How to organize Android app as well as separate library

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an Android library, as well as a series of example applications that use this library. The ideal structure I'd like to have is:

```
projectname/
|-- examples/
|  |-- exampleapp1/
|  |-- exampleapp2/
|-- librarycode/
```

So far I've only been able to figure out how to add libraries that are within the application itself (i.e. exampleapp1/librarycode), but I assume there must be a way to set this up. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to say this project structure is **not an ideal way**. Reasons are as below:

1. Android Studio won't recommend a project structure more than 2 levels as this is not easy to manage and maintain. What if you have **many libraries** rather than **only ONE**? Android Studio only works well with **TWO** level of project structure by the time of answering your question.
2. If your product is an Android library module, then it is practically correct to make it a standalone project compared with mixing it with the example projects that use this library from engineering point of view.
3. Your example projects should be constructed from the customers' point of view to use your library module. The way how customer use your lib should be totally transparent to your library project structure. And your customer should only see your final library deliverable, i.e. either `.aar` or `.jar` files.

So, probably the best option for your case is to **create TWO projects**, one is your library project and the other one is your example projects that use your library, i mean, as the form of `.aar` or `.jar`. The advantages are as below:

1. Your library project can be developed, compiled and built independently on your example projects.
2. You can always use your example projects from user's point of view without being bothered with any internal details of your library, e.g. project structure, dependencies management.
3. Separating your library product from the users development environment will give you a better software configuration management experience. The point is don't mix them altogether!!!

Specifically, your project structure should be something like below:

The example project structure should be:

```
examples/
|-- exampleapp1/
|-- exampleapp2/
|-- exampleapp3/
```

The library project structure should be:

```
projectname/
|-- library1/
|-- library2/
|-- library3/
```